# Best puzzles of 2021 Q2 (April - June)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the second quarter ( April / May / June) 2021?
>
> ---

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):

> **Algorithmically selected "best of"**:
>
> - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2021 Q2](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2021&month=4#query-results)
> - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2021 Q2](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2021&month=4#query-results)
>
> **Best by votes/views:**
>
> - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2021 Q2](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2021/04/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2021 Q2](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2021/04/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2021 Q2](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2021/04/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

<sub>Q: Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>
<sub>A: Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.</sub>

<sub>Q: What's the point?</sub>
<sub>A1: To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
<sub>A2: To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
<sub>A3: To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

## [R᠎e᠎d᠎u᠎n᠎d᠎ancy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109708/redundancy) by [noneuclideanisms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22856/noneuclideanisms)

At the time this was solved, I commented:

> *Wow. This puzzle is incredible - never seen anything that uses ambigrams in this way before! Brilliant solve too - very well done :)*

I wasn't the only one to exude about it:

> *Incredible puzzle!* - **Matthew Jensen**

> *This is an incredibly clever puzzle! If I hadn’t joined this stack already I’d join it just to upvote this.* - **Fivesideddice**

> *Wow what a superb puzzle! That must have taken hours to make.* - **Dmitry Kamenetsky**

(and more...)

These comments speak for themselves (and you should *definitely* go check out this puzzle if you haven't already). It's a wonderful visual puzzle whose secret lies in the world of [ambigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram) and visual 'redundancy' (hence the title). With beautifully-crafted visuals this cleverly-devised teaser is a puzzle that once you come across it, you won't forget it in a hurry.

Bold, inventive and memorable. Fantastic.

Comment: That puzzle was 20/20!!!

Answer (score 1):

### [A Puzzling Easter Egg Hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109224/a-puzzling-easter-egg-hunt) By [Stiv](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)

First of all, I have to say, Stiv has made some memorable puzzles on this site, like his [Puzzle Type Needs A Name Extreme Edition](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102465/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name-extreme-edition) puzzle.  That itself was cool, but I think he's done something extra: Making a puzzle from C4s! He himself [admitted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/111724/72797) that he never thought of making a hidden puzzle in the C4 until he saw the record breaking C4 by Sp3000 (link is in the link). I must say, that puzzle was challenging, mind-bending, and overall, **Incredible**.